# How to set a UIPickerView selected value from Realm?

Tags: swift, realm, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I have setup a viewcontroller where there are 7 "questions" and 7 "answers". I've created a UIPickerView that allows users to select their answer when they click on the answer's UITextField, and save it in realm.

However, when a user has already selected an answer (example: "Agree"), "Agree" doesn't show up as the selected row in the UIPickerView when I click the UITextField for that answer.

How do I set the default or "selectedrow" for the UIPickerview to the answer that is displayed in the UITextField and is saved in Realm?

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupDelegateForPickerView()
        setupDelegatesForTextFields()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadAnswers()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Question1TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question2TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question3TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question4TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question5TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question6TextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Question7TextField: UITextField!

    // Setting up a UIPickerview from the ToolbarPickerView class

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var answers: Results<Answer>?

    var answerArray = [UITextField]()

    func loadAnswers() {
        var answersGiven = realm.objects(Answer.self).filter("id = 1")
        for answer in answersGiven {
            Question1TextField.text = answer.Answer1
            Question2TextField.text = answer.Answer2
            Question3TextField.text = answer.Answer3
            Question4TextField.text = answer.Answer4
            Question5TextField.text = answer.Answer5
            Question6TextField.text = answer.Answer6
            Question7TextField.text = answer.Answer7
        }
    }

    let pickerView = ToolbarPickerView()

    let Menu = ["Strongly Disagree",
                "Disagree",
                "Neutral",
                "Agree",
                "Strongly Agree"]

    var selectedMenu : String?

    func setupDelegatesForTextFields() {
        //appending textfields in an array
        answerArray += [Question1TextField, Question2TextField, Question3TextField, Question4TextField, Question5TextField, Question6TextField, Question7TextField]
        //using the array to set up the delegates, inputview for pickerview and also the inputAccessoryView for the toolbar
        for answer in answerArray {
            answer.delegate = self
            answer.inputView = pickerView
            answer.inputAccessoryView = pickerView.toolbar
        }
    }

    func setupDelegateForPickerView() {
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.toolbarDelegate = self
    }

    func setDefaultValue(item: String, inComponent: Int){
     if let indexPosition = Menu.firstIndex(of: item){
       pickerView.selectRow(indexPosition, inComponent: inComponent, animated: true)
     }
    }

        // Dismissing Keyboard on tapped
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

extension QuestionViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}

extension QuestionViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.Menu.count
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.Menu[row]
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let answer = Answer()
        answer.id = 1


        // Check if the textfield isFirstResponder.
        if Question1TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question1TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer1 = Question1TextField.text

            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer1": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question2TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question2TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer2 = Question2TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer2": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question3TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question3TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer3 = Question3TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer3": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question4TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question4TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer4 = Question4TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer4": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question5TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question5TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer5 = Question5TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer5": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question6TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question6TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer6 = Question6TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer6": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else if Question7TextField.isFirstResponder {
            Question7TextField.text = self.Menu[row]
            answer.Answer7 = Question7TextField.text
            try! realm.write {
                realm.create(Answer.self, value: ["id": 1, "Answer7": self.Menu[row]], update: .modified)
            }
        } else {
        //log errors
        }
    }
}

extension QuestionViewController: ToolbarPickerViewDelegate {

    func didTapDone() {
      let row = self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
      self.pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
      selectedMenu = self.Menu[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func didTapCancel() {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Here is the Toolbar Class just incase.

```
import UIKit

protocol ToolbarPickerViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapDone()
    func didTapCancel()
}

class ToolbarPickerView: UIPickerView {

    public private(set) var toolbar: UIToolbar?
    public weak var toolbarDelegate: ToolbarPickerViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneTapped))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelTapped))

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 44.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
                    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 44.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
                    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 44.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Clinton", size: 14)], for: UIControl.State.normal)

        self.toolbar = toolBar
    }

    @objc func doneTapped() {
        self.toolbarDelegate?.didTapDone()
    }

    @objc func cancelTapped() {
        self.toolbarDelegate?.didTapCancel()
    }
}

extension String {
    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyFormatting() -> String {
        if let value = Double(self) {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
            if let str = formatter.string(for: value) {
                return str
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you put all your code here. selecting a row in a picker view is as simple as you wrote it `self.pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`. doesn't matter if you get your data from realm or not. try to get the row that you need. 
it seems that you take the selected row and set it as the selected, which does nothing.
try to look at this line, I think this is where your problem is:      
`let row = self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)`

Comment: That is in the func didTapDone(), which would only run when the user hits the Done button. I agree that self.pickerView.selectRow (or possible .selectedRow) is most likely the function needed to display the correct answer that has been saved in Realm. But when I click on the UITextField for an answer that has previously been answered (and saved in Realm), how can I make sure that that answer is the default selected row when the UIPickerView is loaded?